# Unable to do Stacking for a Multi-label classifier

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, multilabel-classification, ensemble-learning

I am working on a multi-label text classification problem (Total target labels 90). The data distribution has a long tail and class imbalance and around 100k records. I am using the OAA strategy (One against all). I am trying to create an ensemble using Stacking.

Text features : `HashingVectorizer`(number of features 2**20, char analyzer)
TSVD to reduce the dimensionality (n_components=200).

```py
text_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('hashing_vectorizer', HashingVectorizer(n_features=2**20,
                                             analyzer='char')),
    ('svd', TruncatedSVD(algorithm='randomized',
                         n_components=200, random_state=19204))])

feat_pipeline = FeatureUnion([('text', text_pipeline)])

estimators_list = [('ExtraTrees',
                    OneVsRestClassifier(ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators=30,
                                                             class_weight="balanced",
                                                             random_state=4621))),
                   ('linearSVC',
                    OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC(class_weight='balanced')))]
estimators_ensemble = StackingClassifier(estimators=estimators_list,
                                         final_estimator=OneVsRestClassifier(
                                             LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs',
                                                                max_iter=300)))

classifier_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('features', feat_pipeline),
    ('clf', estimators_ensemble)])
```

Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-ad4e769a0a78> in <module>()
      1 start = time.time()
----> 2 classifier_pipeline.fit(X_train.values, y_train_encoded)
      3 print(f"Execution time {time.time()-start}")
      4 

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in column_or_1d(y, warn)
    795         return np.ravel(y)
    796 
--> 797     raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
    798 
    799 

ValueError: bad input shape (89792, 83)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`StackingClassifier` does not support multi label classification as of now. You could get to understand these functionalities by looking at the shape value for the `fit` parameters such as [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.StackingClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.StackingClassifier.fit).

Solution would be to put the OneVsRestClassifier wrapper on top of `StackingClassifier` rather on the individual models.

Example:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_multilabel_classification
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.ensemble import StackingClassifier
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier

X, y = make_multilabel_classification(n_classes=3, random_state=42)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, 
                                                    test_size=0.33,
                                                    random_state=42)

estimators_list = [('ExtraTrees', ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators=30, 
                                                       class_weight="balanced", 
                                                       random_state=4621)),
                   ('linearSVC', LinearSVC(class_weight='balanced'))]

estimators_ensemble = StackingClassifier(estimators=estimators_list,
                                         final_estimator = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs', max_iter=300))

ovr_model = OneVsRestClassifier(estimators_ensemble)

ovr_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
ovr_model.score(X_test, y_test)

# 0.45454545454545453

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
confusion_matrix(
    y_train[:, 0], 
    ovr_model.estimators_[0].estimators_[0].predict(X_train),)

#array([[818,   0],
#       [  0, 522]])

ovr_model.estimators_[0].estimators_[0].feature_importances_

#array([0.05049793, 0.07232525, 0.05278524, 0.08005984, 0.05036507,
#       0.03674032, 0.06144285, 0.03473714, 0.04080104, 0.05120309,
#       0.05311589, 0.04119592, 0.03239608, 0.08101098, 0.03522335,
#       0.03676684, 0.04613645, 0.04755277, 0.05268342, 0.04296053])
```

Comment: Thanks for the code; it works for me. Could you please share the remaining parts of the code on how to get confusion matrices for all of these estimators as well as variable importance and graphs for individual models? Thanks a lot

Comment: Individual models can be accessed using the `estimators_` attribute

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there any way I can extract the accuracy and predictions "per class" in the multi-class task from the "ensemble model" or the "meta learner"/ "final estimator"? What I need is the final (ensemble) model's confusion matrix, accuracy per class, and how to plot it. I'll be grateful for it; thanks a lot.

Comment: I followed your addition to the above code (confusion matrix part) but it throws an error: `ValueError: Can only tuple-index with a MultiIndex`. I can copy the entire error part if needed. Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I think you have your target values as pandas series, convert it to an array of multi-hot encoding.